# Access control problems with cache-control and canvas

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control

I'm trying to use browser canvas to manipulate images I have hosted on cloudfront. I'm trying to setup cloudfront to have the browser cache images with cache control max-age and still allow canvas to edit those images.

Here's an image that I can edit:

https://d2t4fc8ff77neh.cloudfront.net/cardSrcImage/1ac01l796_16dbmg07t_books2.jpg

Here's one that I can't (Image from origin 'https://d2t4fc8ff77neh.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.):

https://d2t4fc8ff77neh.cloudfront.net/cardSrcImage/1ac01o3l0_16dbmg07t_books2.jpg

The only thing different is the cache-controls header. What's wrong? Thanks.

I'm using the node.js knox library to upload. Example headers:

```
var headers = {
  'Content-Length': options.data.length,
  'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
  // 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=31536000',
  'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
  'Content-Type': options.type
}
```

Comment: To address the "...therefore not allowed access" error, you might try adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*'` to your `headers` object; this allows [`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for everyone, but could at least rule out that issue.

Comment: @Castaglia I added that but still has the same problem. I thought the x-amz-acl public read was the amazon equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I assume you want to just load the images and don't want to save(`POST`) them back to the same `URI`. And this works!

[Here](http://jsbin.com/bahivexoja/edit?js,console,output) is a jsbin that works for both images. Here is the code:

```
var img1 = new Image();
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


//drawing of the test image - img1
img1.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
};

//img1.src = 'https://d2t4fc8ff77neh.cloudfront.net/cardSrcImage/1ac01l796_16dbmg07t_books2.jpg';
img1.src = 'https://d2t4fc8ff77neh.cloudfront.net/cardSrcImage/1ac01o3l0_16dbmg07t_books2.jpg';
```

And the `canvas` in the html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

So your problem is probably how you load the images, but you haven't showed us your code for that.

#### The caching/cross-origin Problem

Your Problem is that the `<img>` tag and the Javascript `Image` have a very different behavior. You can include images from all over the internet with an `<img>` tag without any origin check, but for the Javascript `Image` you the same origin policy is active.

In your original `HTML` you have `<img>` Tags for your image. This makes your browser fetch the images without an `Origin` header. This results in your Server not sending the CORS Headers.

Later when you use the Javascript `Image` your browser has a cached version **without the CORS headers** and will respond with that. So the request will fail!

Sometimes it looked like chrome is intelligent enough to make an additional request, but this is definitely not ideal.

Now it should be easy to fix this. Maybe first use the `Image` and later the `<img>` tag, or just don't use an `<img>` tag at all. You also could always sent CORS Headers for `*`, even when no `Origin` Header is present.

---

You also have a strange Problem in your `resizing` function, but I think this is content for a new question if you can't resolve it yourself.

Comment: The image editing works fine for the first image but not the second one because of CORS. Please try it and you'll see.

Comment: The jsbin *does* exactly that and works for me. Please show your not working code! Also: what browser are you using? Does the jsbin show the image in the canvas for you?

Comment: Oh I apologize. Something is strange, at the time I posted the second image did not resize as I wanted and the first image did. Now both images no longer resize under my code. I was able to upload another one that did. Weird! http://jsbin.com/kikinucowi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Yes your jsbin works for me. Sorry about that maybe something is wrong with my code. I copied it mostly from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/

Comment: Okay, I think I've seen both of your Problems. And I'm pretty sure they are completely unrelated. First you have some really strange caching problem. Second you sometimes can't resize your image. But this is because of a bug in your `resizing` function. `e.originalEvent.touches` is sometimes `undefined`.

Comment: Nice find... Thank you! how did you know about this? Looks like there's a thread for it here. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409090

Comment: Chromes dev tools is all you need to debug this. First you notice difference behavior from with disabled caching, Next analyze the request and responses and think about what is different.